serverMiddleware and CORS problem on Nuxt2
When requesting weather API, It shows CORS problem and blocks the API request, in order to avoid that I tried using serverMiddleware, but got error 500
In the beginning everthing was working fine. Then run into CORS problem.
I needed to solve only on FrontEnd  without Backend, AI chatbots suggested that Nuxt2 built-in  proxy and serverMiddleware are ccn be solution, but itself could not solve it
After some research I found a few solutions, these are:
SSR via ssr: true and used proxy, serverMiddleware.
Here's what I did
nuxt.config.js:
export default: {
ssr: true,

// other conf

modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/proxy'
  ],

  serverMiddleware: [
    { path: '/api/weather', handler: '~/serverMiddleware/weather.js' }
  ],
  axios: {
    proxy: true,
  },
  // Axios module configuration
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    key: process.env.key || '9aaeaf022c454224b26121814242504'
  },

// ... other conf
}

serverMiddleware/weather.js:
import axios from 'axios';
export default async function (req, res) {
  const { key, city } = req.query
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json', {
      params: {
        key
        q: city,
        aqi: 'no',
        alerts: 'no'
      }
    })
    res.json(response.data)
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ err: 'Internal Server Error' })
  }
}

response to call the data in the store and dispatch it to other components:
store/index.js:
export const state = () => ({
  selectedCity: 'Tashkent', // default city,
  data: null
})

export const mutations = {
  SET_SELECTED_CITY(state, city) {
    state.selectedCity = city
  },
  SET_DATA(state, data) {
    state.data = data
  }
}

export const actions = {
  async fetchData({ commit, state }) {
    try {
      const data = await this.$axios.$get('/api/weather', {
        params: {
          key: this.$config.key,
          q: state.selectedCity,
          aqi: 'no',
          alerts: 'no'
        }
      })
      commit('SET_DATA', data)
      return data
    } catch (err) {
      throw err
    }
  }
}

But as a result, got http://localhost:3000/api/weather?key=9aaeaf022c454224b26121814242504&q=Tashkent&aqi=no&alerts=no 500 (RuntimeError)

So rather than solving the CORS problem itself, are you gonna try to use a complex setup to bypass it? I wrote a few answers with serverMiddleware but I do not see how it could be relevant. Using AI is a waste of time and might even be dangerous, aka you should use Nuxt3 for your stuff nowadays. You should also consider the fact that Nuxt3 has baked-in backend capabilities, enough to help you with your issue. But in the end, if you have a CORS issue, rather than using 15 tricks to bypass it, why not give what it wants and solve it at the root?
